# ios swift3 xcode8 coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm learning ios development with swift3. I made my tables and then I go to EDIT -> create `NSManagedObject` subclass. Problem is that generated classes has lots of errors here's the generated code

```
Store+CoreDataClass.swift
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Store)
public class Store: NSManagedObject {

}
```

---

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Store {

   @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Store> {
      return NSFetchRequest<Store>(entityName: "Store");
   }

   @NSManaged public var name: String?
   @NSManaged public var toImage: Image?
   @NSManaged public var toItem: NSSet?

}
```

---

```
Store+CoreDataProperties.swift
// MARK: Generated accessors for toItem
extension Store {

    @objc(addToItemObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToToItem(_ value: Item)

    @objc(removeToItemObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromToItem(_ value: Item)

    @objc(addToItem:)
    @NSManaged public func addToToItem(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeToItem:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromToItem(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

And here's the error that it gives me

> @NSManaged only allowed on an instance property or method}

So why is that? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Swift 3 you don't have to create NSManagedObject subclass, the system will generate it for you so you can access it without it.
However if you do want to generate it anyway, go to the xcdatamodel and make sure to set the Codegen over the Data Model inspetor to be "Manual/None", and then generate it:

[I've attached this image for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsVxx.png)

Comment: That actually has nothing to do with Swift 3. It's Xcode 8 that creates the subclasses.